# Estimating current when voltage drops > voltage input

Tags: led, circuit-analysis, diodes, schematics

Let's say I have a circuit with a 5V battery and a 2V LED and a 100 ohm resistor. Ignoring certain properties of an LED, I can estimate the current by doing:

```
3V / 100 ohms ==> ~30 mA
```

However, what happens when I have 3 LEDs in the circuit? Using the above approach, I would get a current of zero (or an open circuit or whatever it would be called). But this isn't really the case, as shown in a simulator, where I get ~1 mA:

[image]

Does using the voltage-drop approach not work where there may be more drops than the input can support? If so, what would be an example of calculating the below circuit to get something 'close to' 1mA .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your initial calculation, you assumed that the LED will drop 2V no matter what current is flowing through it. In practice its voltage will vary depending on the current. If you have a data sheet for the LED, it should specify the current vs. voltage for the LED over some reasonable range. In your simulated circuit, you put 3 LEDs in series across a 5V source.  Assuming the LEDs are identical, then each one will drop 1/3 of 5V or 1.67 volts which is what your simulator shows. However the current depends on the actual current/voltage characteristics of your LED. The simulator probably assumed some generic model and came up with a current of 823 uA. That is not unreasonable for an LED operating well below its rated voltage but the exact value, as already mentioned, depends on the particular characteristics of your LED. This is true in general when operating devices above or below their ratings.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this graphically, if you have a current vs. voltage curve for the LED. This is an actual measured curve for a red LED.

I can't use your exact example because the voltage is outside of the curve. But, here is a similar analysis. If your voltage was 6V, and you had 3 of these LEDs in series, what would the current be?

6V / 3 LEDs = 2V per LED.

Find the intersection of the curve and read the current, about 4.4 mA.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Again, I don't know the actual parameter values that your simulator is using. But it is probably using something like \$\eta=4\$ (the emission co-efficient.) You know about \$V_T=\frac{k\,T}{q}\$ as the thermal temperature voltage and again I'm going to assume a saturation current of \$100\:\text{pA}\$ for the LED and thereby move directly to a closed solution.

The diode voltage is:

$$V_\text{D}=\eta\cdot V_T\cdot\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{I_\text{D}}{I_\text{SAT}}+1\right)$$

Using KVL, we find the following (\$V_\text{CC}\$ is the power supply voltage):

$$\begin{align*}
V_\text{CC}-3\cdot\eta\cdot V_T\cdot\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{I_\text{D}}{I_\text{SAT}}+1\right)&=0\:\text{V}\\\\
\frac{V_\text{CC}}{3\cdot\eta\cdot V_T}&=\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{I_\text{D}}{I_\text{SAT}}+1\right)\\\\
e^{^\frac{V_\text{CC}}{3\,\cdot\,\eta\,\cdot\, V_T}}&=\frac{I_\text{D}}{I_\text{SAT}}+1\\\\
e^{^\frac{V_\text{CC}}{3\,\cdot\,\eta\,\cdot\, V_T}}-1&=\frac{I_\text{D}}{I_\text{SAT}}\\\\&\therefore\\\\I_\text{D}&=I_\text{SAT}\cdot\left(e^{^\frac{\left[\frac{V_\text{CC}}3\right]}{\eta\,\cdot\, V_T}}-1\right)
\end{align*}$$

Which is what you'd expect. This is just the Shockley diode equation, except that \$V_\text{CC}\$ has been divided into three parts before computing the result.

Using \$V_T\approx 26\:\text{mV}\$, I find \$I_\text{D}\approx 912\:\mu\text{A}\$. Which isn't far from what you got.

(For others not yet following along with all the "David" questions recently, there was another one where I used \$\eta\approx 4\$ and \$I_\text{SAT}=100\:\text{pA}\$ as approximations for the diode he is simulating. I kept these values here, too, for consistency.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't force voltage drop.

Suppose you have three identical things which drop 5V each.  And you connect them across a 9V supply.  What actually happens?  **They drop 3 volts each**.  Why? Because *they have to*.

So what happened?  Clearly you got that 5V voltage drop number from *somewhere*: a data sheet, or calculations.  Both would have made certain assumptions about the default or nominal conditions.  The data sheets explicitly say that.  For instance a lot of lighting LEDs that advertise 1400ma, you read the data sheet and all the data on it is based on testing at 350ma, and the data sheet typically shows you how performance varies up to 1400ma, expressing it as a percentage of nominal at 350ma.

So you need to figure out the drop you're going to get, either by guesswork (the 3V above) or measurement, and go see what the data sheet says about that.